# Is it possible to download the updates via torrent?

Tags: package-management, updates, bittorrent

Is there software for Ubuntu, which allowes me to download and share the OS update packages with torrent? I want to relieve the servers of Canonical, so I already set up an apt cache server. But it would be really great to use ubuntu nearly fully independent of foreign servers.

It is clear to me, that there must be servers storing the hashes. But there are torrent solutions like Tribler, which doesn't need any server.

Comment: Maybe it can be done with apt-torrent? Also there's something called apt p2p, see http://torrentfreak.com/use-bittorrent-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-intrepid-ibex-081029/

Comment: Thats a good article, I'm just trying it. Is there a possibility to use apt-p2p together with apt-cacher?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea. I've just heard of these technologies and never tried them. Hopefully someone else knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible, maybe, chaotic, very. Please have a look at the [debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/DebTorrent) about this and the possible issues that you will have using BT as a download source for your updates.

There is a reason why when looking in google for "apt torrent good setup" or "working perfect" returns 0 good results will all the keywords.

Comment: OK... this seems to be very difficult.. Maybe I should just keep my apt-cacher..

Comment: The problem is a mix of small files downloads, security and good implementation. Its all related to the BT protocol, maybe another protocol exists but on the current state of things there is no perfect solution using BT, and after all we are talking about updates, you don't want to use "updates" and "not perfect" on the same sentence too often! ;) If you find anything else that works for you edit your question and let other ppl know about it. At the moment I have no idea. Gl